# is there any way to identify if a file is still being copied from one directory to other

Tags: linux, nfs, lsof

Have a file `File.txt` and if any process is trying to copy the file from `/source/` to `/destination/`

Is there a way to identify if the file `File.txt` (or any other file ) available in  `/destination/`  is completely copied, or the process is still going on.

I tried `lsof` but its not working

```
**Error** : lsof: WARNING: can't stat() nfs file system
```

Any suggestions

Comment: install `progress` and run `progress -m` and it should be able to tell you.  If your command is not a well-known command run `progress -m -c my_command`.  Or install `pv`, which also works but it requires the PID to be supplied, as in `pv -d 1234`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **rsync** with **--progress** option next time.

Here is a little snippet that will help you to get the progress status every second until it reaches 100% percent ; Just replace your **source** and **destination** file paths.

```
n="$(du -sh <path_to_your_source_file> | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g')"
while true; do sourcesize="$n" destdir=<path_to_your_dest_file> copyprogress="$(export | du -sh $destdir | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g' )" ; echo "scale=3 ; $copyprogress / $sourcesize * 100" | bc | xargs echo -n ; echo % completed ; sleep 1 ; done
```

[image]

Also you can check whether cp command is still running by using **pidof** and use **ps** to check the full command that is being executed:

[image]

Comment: It's an output instead of code, how could i avoid it ?

Comment: Just copy-paste it directly from your terminal emulator!